# In Message.builder , builder() is showing unresolved reference?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using fcm to send notification from the my android app and i have implemented all the libraries it asked me.

```
            val topic = "highScores"

// See documentation on defining a message payload.
            val message = Message.builder()
                    .putData("score", "850")
                    .putData("time", "2:45")
                    .setTopic(topic)
                    .build()

// Send a message to the devices subscribed to the provided topic.
            val response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message)
// Response is a message ID string.
            println("Successfully sent message: " + response)
```

i'm using this code to send the notification but builder is showing unresolved.

Comment: Check your import for `Message` class . You probably imported the wrong class.

Comment: com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging
 i have imported this

Comment: I am talking about `Message` not `FirebaseMessaging`..

Comment: i tried this com.google.firebase.messaging.Message, but its not importing showing unresolved Message

Comment: You need to import [Message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/Message) . remove import for Message and use `ALT+ ENTER` over message it will show the possible imports list..

Comment: it is suggesting me  these three 1. android.os.Message 2. android.app.Notification.MessagingStyle.Message 3.android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompact.MessagingStyle.Message

Comment: Then you did not added the right dependency to use Firebase `Message` class . Follow the Documentation.

Comment: import com.google.firebase.messaging.Message i'm importing this but it is showing Message unresolved reference

Comment: I have the same issue, also can't find any dependencies i am possibly missing

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.9.0'
```

and make sure you import the right Message class, wich is

```
import com.google.firebase.messaging.Message
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RemoteMessage

```
RemoteMessage message = new RemoteMessage.Builder(getRegistrationToken())
                .setMessageId(incrementIdAndGet())
                .addData("message", "Hello")
                .build();
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
```